# Load specific length of file from specific point of file in Python

Tags: python, string

I have an output from a scientific program, that contains a few occurrences of a table that looks like that:

```
                         Standard orientation:                         
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Center     Atomic      Atomic             Coordinates (Angstroms)
 Number     Number       Type             X           Y           Z
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
      1          7           0       -2.365589   -0.297051    1.870038
      2          6           0       -2.931493    0.222141    0.571475
      3          6           0       -2.646169   -0.877981   -0.469921
```

I need to find the row number of the last occurrence of such table. For now I came up with a partial solution - to read the file line by line, reverse its order and find the "Standard orientation:" phrase. Then get the row number from it's index.

```py
f = open("file.out", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
lines.reverse()
index = lines.index("Standard orientation:")

print(len(lines) - index - 1)
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error that there is no string "Standard orientation:" in my file (when there are over 100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the row number of the last table like this:

```
with open("file.out", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.reverse()
    row = 0
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "Standard orientation:" in line:
            row = index
            break
    row = len(lines) - row # this will refer to a row with the "Standard orientation:" phrase
    print(row)
```

Here I look for that phrase in every line, because the line may contain some other characters along with the phrase we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

index() doesn't return result because each line contains not only the text (printable characters) but whitespace characters as well (spaces, newlines, etc.).

The easiest solution would be searching for substring "Standard orientation:" in the string:

```
string_to_search = "Standard orientation:"
f = open("file.out", "r")
for i, line in enumerate(reversed(f.readlines())):
    if string_to_search in line:
        print(len(lines) - i - 1)
        break
```